# Why my date parser doesn't work in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a json that contains date field:

```
"created_at":"2016-03-06T16:39:29.786Z"
```

in my app I'm doing like this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let created_at = json["created_at"].string
let crd = dateFormatter.dateFromString(created_at!)
print(crd) //prints nil
```

Why am I getting `nil` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote literal text and you are using the wrong format specifier for the hour.

The `T` must be quoted.

`hh` is for 12-hour format but you have 24-hour format which is `HH`.

So you want:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Comment: ok, but now when I'm doing: `print(created_at); print(crd)` I'm getting two different values: `Optional("2016-03-07T21:19:26.277Z")` and `Optional(2016-03-07 21:19:26 +0000)`. What might be the reason of that?

Comment: The first is the original string, the second is the log output of an `NSDate`. Both represent the same date. Why do you expect the two outputs to be the same? What you are seeing is correct.

Comment: Worth chucking in ye standard QA1480 `en_US_POSIX` recommendation, so that your phone doesn't silently convert twenty-four-hour format to twelve-hour? (though I've already voted positively)